# Fiddler: Creating an AutoResponse rule to map all calls to one host to another host

Tags: proxy, fiddler, auto-responder

Example:
I want to create **one** AutoResponse rule that will map all calls to one host to another host, but *preserve the urls*.  Examples

http://hostname1/foo.html ->  http://hostname2/foo.html

and

http://hostname1/js/script.js -> http://hostname2/js/script.js

**in one rule.**
For now, I've accomplished this by creating aN AutoResponse rule for every URL my project calls, but I'm sure there must be a way to right one rule using the right wildcards.  I looked at http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp, but I couldn't see how to do it.  The wild cards all seem to be around the matching and not the action.

Full context:  *I'm developing on a beta platform and Visual Studio is borked in such away that it is sending all the requests to http://localhost:24575 when my project is actually running on http://localhost:56832*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To map from one host to another, don't use AutoResponder. Instead, click Tools > Hosts.

Alternatively, you can click Rules > Customize Rules, scroll to OnBeforeRequest and write a bit of code:

```
if (oSession.HostnameIs("localhost") && (oSession.port == 24575)) oSession.port = 56832;
```

Comment: What if I also need to map the path in the URL to a different path?

Answer (score 19):

This is how I configured Fiddler2 :

```
I want to redirect all requests from http://server-name/vendor-portal-html/ to http://localhost/vendor-portal-html/
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
REGEX:.*/vendor-portal-html/(.*)   to    http://127.0.0.1/vendor-portal-html/$1
```

[image]

Thanks to EricLaw for above comment.

Answer (score 6):

Because this was way harder to find than it should have been to use Fiddler to *redirect* all requests for one to host to another host:

Use the AutoResponder tab to set a rule such that any request matching your old host will redirect to your new host with the path and query string appended.

Match with regex options `ix` to make it case-insensitive and ignore whitespace. Leave off the `n` option as [it requires explicitly named capture groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Capture the path and query string of the request and append it to the redirect response using the variable `$1`, where the path+query is the first capture group. You can use capture groups `$1`-`$n` if your regex has more.

Fiddler will then issue an `HTTP 307` redirect response.

Request: `regex:^(?ix)http://old.host.com/(.*)$ #Match HTTP host`

Response: `*redir:http://new.host.com/$1`

[image: Redirect old host to new host]

**Request**

```
GET http://old.host.com/path/to/file.html HTTP/1.1
Host: old.host.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 307 AutoRedir
Content-Length: 0
Location: http://new.host.com/path/to/file.html
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

Comment: side question is there a way to define request type (say only POST requests)

Answer (score 2):

Mapping requests with Fiddler Autoresponder using Regular Expressions is possible.
This can be done with rexexp rules. However this doesn't seem to be documented  anywhere.

If you add a rule and use regular expressions within parenthesis, these matches can be used in the desired mapping when using the placeholders   ... $n

each number corresponds to the matched regexp in the rule.

```
Example of Rule: regex:http://server1/(\w*) -> http://server2/

This will result in the following mapping: http://server1/foo.html -> http://server2/foo.html
```

Comment: Regular expressions are documented in the Fiddler book, in the Help page linked on the AutoResponder tab, and on my blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/01/09/fiddler-2.3.8.2-beta-views-woff-mp3-h264-datauris-and-autoresponder-supports-regular-expression-groups.aspx

Comment: Nice stuff. I've google it desperately with no success. This is a major feature indeed. Cool blog about Fiddler!