# Mock GET http requests for a web app when testing using Selenium

Tags: json, unit-testing, selenium, mocking, httprequest

I have an `AngularJS` application and I'm using `Selenium` to do UI testing using `C#`.

My web app is sending **GET** requests to a specific server (say `http://localhost:8082`).

What would be the best way to mock the response of these requests? I don't want my server to run for these tests, and also for testing purposes it would be best to setup the returned **JSON**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do it is with fiddler- all you need to do is setting fiddler as a proxy, and configure an auto responder.
take a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32812386/1447518

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by using a tool such as http://mock-server.com, http://mocky.io or https://github.com/jmartin82/mmock.