# Fiddler: How to redirect paths from one domain to another

Tags: redirect, https, fiddler

I want to use Fiddler to redirect URL requests from: 
"https://pstatic.fo.local:8088/....." to "https://127.0.0.1:8088/...."

For example, a request to "https://servername:8088/hello/world/index.html" will be redirected to "https://127.0.0.1:8088/hello/world/index.html".

I read the following post:
[Fiddler: Creating an AutoResponse rule to map all calls to one host to another host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960993/fiddler-creating-an-autoresponse-rule-to-map-all-calls-to-one-host-to-another-h)

and I used Rule Editor to do this redirect:

[image]

It didn't succeed.
I also tried:

regex:https://pstatic.fo.local:8088/(.*)  --> https://127.0.0.1:8088/$1

regex:https://pstatic.fo.local:8088/(.*)  --> https://127.0.0.1:8088/$0

Whenever I enter the browser and type: 
https://pstatic.fo.local:8088/hello/world/index.html

I get the following in the browser:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   pstatic.fo.local (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Do you know what I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 7):

The option:

> regex:https://pstatic.fo.local:8088/(.*) --> https://127.0.0.1:8088/$1

is the right one.

What I had to do it enable the option of handling HTTPS requests. 
It can be done by: 
Tools-> Telerik Fiddler Optoins -> HTTPS-> tick the options "Capture HTTPS CONNECTs" and "Decrypt HTTPS traffic".